# Using Parse.com To Pass WinForm Data To Parse.com DataBase

Tags: c#, winforms, parse-platform

I would like to ask you guys out there is it possible for a C# windows form application to be using parse.com to pass the data collected by the windows form to parse.com Database ??

Comment: thanks for your comment i manage to pass data into parse.com its quite an easy step actually

Comment: It would be nice to tell us what you did...Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout their [`REST API`](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest) which would allow you to send HTTP requests from your WinForms application.

Comment: thanks for your comment i manage to pass into parse.com database

Comment: In fact the REST API documentation does not mention anything usable in Windows Forms application!